# Optimizar código en python con web scraping

Tags: python, bucles

Hola estoy haciendo un código pero tarda mucho en ejecutar, funciona bien pero tarda mucho.
Explicando el código:
array_articulos tiene 11 columnas.
si array_articulos[10] es igual a 0. guardo la url del articulo y comienza el scraper. 
consigo el color del articulo y lo comparo con mi array de colores para ver si existe. (array_colores tiene 3, una columna con el nombre del color y la segunda tiene el nombre equivalente, por ej. "NEGRO" y "NEGRA".

Sí existe, lo guardo en el array_articulo en su columna correspondiente.
Tarda más de 20min ejecutando.
Se agradece cualquier ayuda. Saludos

```
for articulo in array_articulos:
try:
    if(articulo[10] == 0):

        url = articulo[8]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
        color = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("td")]

        for b in range(len(color)):

            if(color[b].find("Color") != -1):
                color_auxiliar = elimina_tildes(color[b+1]).upper()

                for NombreColor in array_colores:

                    if(color_auxiliar.find(NombreColor[1]) != -1 or color_auxiliar.find(NombreColor[1]) != -1):
                        articulo[10] = color_auxiliar
except:
    print("NOT FOUND: ",url)




def elimina_tildes(cadena):
s = ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD',cadena) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
return s
```

Comment: para poder ayudarte necesitamos replicar tu codigo y ver donde esta fallando.
pero si solo pones un extracto tan superficial no podremos saber que hace del todo como por ejemplo `elimina_tildes` debes colocar un ejemplo mas completo!

Comment: @Bryro  gracias, ahi lo edite

Comment: sige aun muy superficial mejor coloca la url  y dinos que deseas extraer de la misma!

Comment: @Bryro Es un scraper, son 10mil urls. saco la etiqueta donde tiene el color, que esta dentro del elemento html <td>

Comment: y todas las 10mils url tiene la misma estructura :O que es una plantilla wordpress?

Comment: todas con la misma estructura, html. esta seria una https://www.dafiti.com.ar/Jean-Pato-Pampa-Serena-288915.html

Comment: esta no tiene `td` o esta no es relevante.... `nota:` si son tantas solicitudes lo mejor seria usar `hilos`

Comment: nunca use hilos, si tenes algun ejemplo me seria muy útil. busco donde dice Color, y el elemento proximo seria el nombre del color. esa fue mi pobre manera de buscar el nombre del color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacer algo asi:

```
import threading

def articulos(articulo):
    try:
        if(articulo[10] == 0):

            url = articulo[8]
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
            color = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in soup.find_all("td")]

            for b in range(len(color)):

                if(color[b].find("Color") != -1):
                    color_auxiliar = elimina_tildes(color[b+1]).upper()

                    for NombreColor in array_colores:

                        if(color_auxiliar.find(NombreColor[1]) != -1 or color_auxiliar.find(NombreColor[1]) != -1):
                            articulo[10] = color_auxiliar
    except:
        print("NOT FOUND: ",url)

# con hilos no debemos esperar la ejecucion de articulos
# cada uno se ejecutara en un hilo separado

for articulo in array_articulos:
    # configuamos el hilo
    thread = threading.Thread(target=articulos, args=(articulo,))
    # le damos start
    thread.start()
```

Comment: la funcion articulos deberia devolver el array?

Comment: return array! :v

Comment: La pregunta fue respondida con éxito. muchas gracias, se optimizó el código